# Symfony2 production error

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans

I'm developping Symfony2 applications on my local computer that runs with Mac OS. Each time that I go online to deploy my symfony2 project, I experience some difficulties.

I know I should get Linux working and it's a work in progress. However, I would like to know if there are some tips to detect error.

For instance:

**Pb 1 :** I had a problem with the mapped super class annotation.
**Solution  :** It was a case sensitive problem. So I put the correct spelling and it went fine.

**Pb 2 :** I was having a problem with an empty $_POST (both Request object and $_POST were empty despite the fact that I was actually posting stuff - my application was working fine on my local computer).

**Solution (very unreliable) :** I uninstalled manually a bundle (commented it's route and it's call in the Kernel) and reinstalled it manually (by uncommenting the previous commented stuff). Normally, it shouldn't change anything. But now my `$_POST` is not empty any more! Yes I did emptied the cache many times. So basically I don't know what solved the issue.

What I'm trying to get here is some tips on how to successfully deploy an application that works locally and how to detect what problems are making the application not working on line. The empty $_POST is very annoying and I still don't know what was going on.

**Precision :** I'm developing with Netbeans and I'm now using the remote website run configuration. Basically, each time I save a file, netbeans push it on my server through ftp and I test the online site instead of the local site.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Pb 1 : Do you have check if you have two environements ISO ? Same PHP, same web server Apache/Nginx or others ?

Comment: did you correctly run a php composer.phar install on your production server , in order to install properly each of your bundles ? you should not copy your bundle folders, but let composer do it instead.

Comment: No. I just checked and localy I'm running with php 5.4.10 and on my ovh account, I'm running with php 4.4.9. Do you think it's related with my first problem?

Comment: Yes, it's  probably this.

Comment: Hi Charles. The problem is that I cannot run composer.phar command on my server (or may be I don't know how to do it). Basically, I'm using the console bundle to run every command involving database schema update or assets installation. But I can't run any composer command...

Comment: Moreover I had a similar issue to pb 2 with acme demo bundle. I uninstalled it and my application worked fine for 1 day and then some error appeared again (empty $_POST). So I uninstalled a second bundle, checked if the problem disapeared and reinstalled it again. Basically the application is running again but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming mostly from my inclusion of FOSJsRouting. The routing file of FOSJsRouting has to be called at the very end of your application "routing.yml". Otherwise, you may experience some unexplicable features.